# recursion structures in perl

Tags: perl

In Perl code I have to call the `ls` function and check it if any child is there. Then I have to call the same function again otherwise perform some action.

For example

```
# call ls Method

sub check_ls {

    $folder = $foo->ls();
    $length = @listing;

    if ( $length > 1 ) {

        #do something
    }
    elsif ( $length == 1 ) {
        check_ls();
    }
}
```

==================================================

```
   Question-2:
```

can anyone describe/edit my below code(And i want to know the flow of the below structure)

```
my $foo=cms::folder_entry->new(); #create a new object of folder_entry class
$root_entry_id =$foo->new_root_folder(folder_name=>'test_root_timestamp'); #now i call the new_root_folder and in return i got the id
my $root = folder_entry_id->new($root_entry_id); #now again create a new object through passing $root_entry_id parameter
```

or the below statement is the correct statement?

```
  my @listing = $root->$foo->ls();
```

Please edit my Comment if i am wrong in secound Question

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code. There is no `elseif` in Perl. It's `elsif`.

Comment: Also your _approach_ doesn't show any function calling beside the one `ls()`, which is a method. It's not clear what you want to do, so there is no way of saying if you are doing it right. Please [edit] your question, fix the syntax error, indent your code in a way that it's legible and describe the problem you are having.

Comment: yes i got it and i update my question so please check it

Comment: @AruneshSingh oky sir and one more thing sir  if i have to pass the arguments to my function then this approach is right or not....
`elsif($length == 1){
            check_ls_version($version);
    }
sub check_ls_version($version){
$folder=$foo->ls(version_number=>$version);
        $length=@listing;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid approach. It's called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), and it's often used to traverse tree-like structures.

It's important to include a condition that will end the recursion.

**However** your code looks like it's not going to work. You are using global variables. You should be using *lexicals* declared using [the `my` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) inside of your function, and you need to pass in the current state into the recursion.

Consider this example of calculating factorials.

```
sub fac {
    my $number = shift;

    return 1 if $number == 1;
    return $number * fac($number - 1);
}

print fac(5);
```

It will go all the way into the recursion down to the deepest level. Then it will calculate *backwards* up the recursion tree. In each call, the lexical variables will be scoped, so they don't clash or get overwritten.

Look at this rewrite with debug output.

```
sub fac {
    my $number = shift;

    print "in: $number\n";

    return 1 if $number == 1;

    my $return = $number * fac($number - 1);
    print "out: $return\n";

    return $return;
}


print fac(5);
```

Here is the output.

```
in: 5
in: 4
in: 3
in: 2
in: 1
out: 2
out: 6
out: 24
out: 120
120
```

---

If you run a Perl that is at least version 5.16, you can use [the `__SUB__` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html) instead of the name of your sub inside of that same sub. It returns a reference to the current subroutine. That way, you can even build recursive anonymous subs. You do need to turn it on with `use feature 'current_sub'` or `use v5.16` though.

```
use feature 'current_sub';

sub fac {
    my $number = shift;

    print "in: $number\n";

    return 1 if $number == 1;

    my $return = $number * __SUB__->($number - 1);
    print "out: $return\n";

    return $return;
}
```

---

Also add [the `use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings 'all'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas to your code to enforce stricter rules that will make it easier to debug your code.

Comment: `if($length == 1){
   foreach my $entry (@listing){
     
    if($entry->{folder_name} eq 'Development'){
   my $new_version_number=$entry->{version_number};
    }
  }
   _check_ls_version($new_version_number); 
  }

sub _check_ls_version($version){

$folder=$foo->ls(version_number=>$version);
   $length=@listing;
    if($folder){
   
   foreach my $entry (@listing){
     
    if($entry->{folder_name} eq 'PerlProject'){
     $new_entryId=$entry->{entry_id};
    }
  }
   }
}`

Comment: @Dhruv what are you trying to say with that?

Comment: *"faculty"*? Do you mean *factorial*?

Comment: @borodin, yes. Sorry, that's a false friend. It's _Fakultät_ in German, which also translates to faculty.